# ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I trying to insert data from one table to other table and using a sequence while but I'm getting the sequence not allowed here error on Oracle 12c.

```
INSERT INTO table_a
(a,b,c,d)
    SELECT
        schema.table_a_seq.nextval,
        t.col1,
        t.col2,
        t.col3
    FROM
        (
            SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_b
        )t;
```

Comment: why don;t you just use `INSERT INTO table_a
(a,b,c,d) SELECT schema.table_a_seq.nextval, col1, col2, col3 FROM table_b`

Comment: It shouldn't have any problem. Are you sure you provided the complete query in the question? Missed an order by or something?

Comment: I tried your query and is it working perfectly fine. Can you try the following query and see whether it is executing fine SELECT schema.table_a_seq.nextval from dual

Comment: Also, any specific reason why you have prefixed your sequence name with your schema name? Does the sequence belong in some other schema?

Comment: Here are some possible causes for the error you are facing, http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287.

Comment: @vkp I tried this INSERT INTO table_a (a,b,c,d) SELECT schema.table_a_seq.nextval, col1, col2, col3 FROM table_b but I got the same error. After I did some googling I changed it to the one which I shown in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the error When I tried to use the schema name before every object in the SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO schema.table_a
(a,b,c,d)
SELECT
    schema.table_a_seq.nextval,
    t.col1,
    t.col2,
    t.col3
FROM
    (
        SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM schema.table_b
    )t;
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the error, However I have changed your query to-

```
INSERT INTO table_a 
SELECT table_a_seq.nextval, t.* 
FROM (SELECT col1 FROM table_b) t;
```

And its working fine for me. You might have missed some part of the query to include here in the question.

The `ORA-02287` can be raised if you used the sequence in the following part of `SELECT` statement.

In a `WHERE` clause

In a `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clause

In a `DISTINCT` clause

Along with a `UNION` or `INTERSECT` or `MINUS`

In a sub-query

Reference:[OraFAQ:ORA-02287](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287)

```
SQL> desc table_a
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER
 COL2                                               NUMBER

SQL> desc table_b
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER
 COL2                                               NUMBER

SQL> select * from table_a;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from table_b;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         2          3
         4          5


SQL> INSERT INTO table_a SELECT table_a_seq.nextval, t.* FROM (SELECT col1 FROM table_b) t;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from table_a;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         3          2
         4          4
```