# ORACLE 12C - ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have created sequnce prac_seq:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE prac_seq
   START WITH 300
   INCREMENT BY 10;
```

And I want to use it the following:

```
UPDATE pracownicy
   SET placa_dod = prac_seq.CURRVAL
   WHERE id_prac = prac_seq.CURRVAL;
```

And then I get an error called:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
>   02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
>   *Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
>              here in the statement.
>   *Action:   Remove the sequence number.

Why I cannot use sequence like above?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: It's not allowed to reference a sequence in the `where` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155090/ora-02287-sequence-number-not-allowed-here)

Comment: The query makes no sense. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 1):

First, the documentation is quite clear on this point:

> Restrictions on Sequence Values
>
> You cannot use CURRVAL and NEXTVAL in the following constructs:
>
> - The WHERE clause of a SELECT statement

I do understand why `NEXTVAL` can't be used.  You think the `WHERE` clause is being executed once, but it is (conceptually) executed for each row.  Having a side-effecting operation in the `WHERE` introduces a host of problems.  The results of the query using an index, for instance, would be different from the results not using an index.

My guess is that the reason is because both values could change while the query is running, and in some cases, the result of the query is not deterministic.